# Using export USER=myName doesn't change the output of whoami

Tags: debian, environment-variables, bashrc, whoami

I saw [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18531524/3424327)

```
$ whoami
MatsP
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x getenv.cpp 
$ ./a.out
MatsP
$ export USER=DonaldDuck
$ ./a.out
DonaldDuck
```

but for me it doesn't work. I am in a Debian machine. I used `export -p` and indeed the variable changed. I refreshed the `bachrc`, still nothing. How to achiece the above? `whoami` displays the default value.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? `whoami` produce the actual user login regardless of `USER` environment variable.

Comment: So `getenv("USER")` is changed by `export USER=myName` but `whoami` remains the same?

Comment: Yes, because `whoami` does not use that variable.

Comment: Ok but using the code I linked above the output from `getenv("USER")` remains the same.

Comment: please paste the output from YOUR system instead of the example.

Comment: The output from my system using `getenv("USER")`is my username. Although I use `export USER=aName` to change the it.

Answer (score 1):

`whoami` on Linux does not read the `USER` variable.

On a "regular system" (meaning not using for example LDAP) it just does a `geteuid(2)` system call to get your current effective userid and then reads `/etc/passwd` to look up your username.

Comment: Ok, but why on my system the code from the link above doesn't work? I used `getenv("USER")` and saw my username and then tried to change it using `export USER=aName` and next time i run `getenv("USER")` it gives the original value.